# Merging two tables including multiple ocurrence of column identifiers

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I would like to merge two tables:

File 1:

> 1 today
>   2 tomorrow
>   3 red

File 2:

> 1 a lot
>   1 sometimes
>   2 at work
>   2 at home
>   2 sometimes
>   3 new

Desired output (file 3):

> 1     today   a lot
>   1     today   sometimes
>   2     tomorrow    at work
>   2     tomorrow    at home
>   2     tomorrow    sometimes
>   3     red new

I came up with the following:

```
awk -F '[\t]' -v OFS='\t' '{i=$1;$1=x} NR==FNR{A[i]=$0;next} A[i]{print i,$0A[i]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

However, it gives me only:

> 1     today   sometimes
>   2     tomorrow    sometimes
>   3     red new

Answer (score 7):

Do you specifically require an `awk` solution? 
`join file1 file2 > file3` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: I like awk, but this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next};{$1 = $1"\t"a[$1]}1' OFS='\t' file1 file2
1   today   a lot
1   today   sometimes
2   tomorrow    at  work
2   tomorrow    at  home
2   tomorrow    sometimes
3   red new
```

Comment: +1. A little terser: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next} {$1=a[$1]} 1' file1 file2`