# Merging two tables including multiple ocurrence of column identifiers and unique lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I asked a similar question yesterday ([Merging two tables including multiple ocurrence of column identifiers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155735/merging-two-tables-including-multiple-ocurrence-of-column-identifiers)) but ran into a problem with unique lines.

I would like to merge two tables based on column 1:

File 1:

> 1 today
>   1 green
>   2 tomorrow
>   3 red

File 2:

> 1 a lot
>   1 sometimes
>   2 at work
>   2 at home
>   2 sometimes
>   3 new
>   4 a lot
>   5 sometimes
>   6 at work

Desired output (file 3):

> 1     today   a lot
>   1     today   sometimes
>   1     green   a lot
>   1     green   sometimes
>   2     tomorrow    at work
>   2     tomorrow    at home
>   2     tomorrow    sometimes
>   3     red new

I came up with the following:

```
awk -F '[\t]' -v OFS='\t' '{i=$1;$1=x} NR==FNR{A[i]=$0;next} A[i]{print i,$0A[i]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

However, it gives me only:

> 1     today   sometimes
>   2     tomorrow    sometimes
>   3     red new

Please note that the solutions in the previous thread (join and awk) would give me a combination of the 2 files including all lines. I would like to have only the lines of file 1 (column 1 as the identifier) but report all matching occurrences in file 2.

Edit:

columns are tab separated

Real File 1:
    fig|395961.4.peg.2627   Bacteria Cyanobacteria unknown unknown  1795

(Column1: fig... Column2: Bacteria... Column3 1795)

Real File 2:
    fig|1000561.3.peg.1838  Cysteine desulfurase (EC 2.8.1.7)   Test - Thiamin  Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments

(Column1: fig... Column2: Cysteine... Column3 Test...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;

my (%file1,%file2);

## Open the 1st file
open(A,"file1");
while(<A>){
    ## Remove trailing newlines
    chomp; 
    ## Split the current line on tabs into the @F array.
    my @F=split(/\t/); 
    ## This is the tricky part. It adds fields 2-last
    ## to the hash $file1. The value of this hash is an array
    ## and the keys are the 1st fields. This will result in a list
    ## of all 1st fields and all their associated columns.
    push @{$file1{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F];
} 


## Open the 2nd file
open(B,"file2");
while(<B>){
    ## Remove trailing newlines
    chomp; 
    ## Split the current line on tabs into the @F array.
    my @F=split(/\t/); 

    ## If the current 1st field was found in file1
    if (defined($file1{$F[0]})) {
        ## For each of the columns associated with
        ## this 1st field in the 1st file.
        foreach my $col (@{$file1{$F[0]}}) {
            print "$F[0]\t$col\t@F[1..$#F]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You could golf it into a (long) one-liner:

```
$ perl -lane 'BEGIN{open(A,"file1"); while(<A>){chomp; @F=split(/\t/); 
                    push @{$k{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F];}  } 
              $k{$F[0]} && print "$F[0]\t@{$k{$F[0]}}\t@F[1..$#F]"' file2
1   today green a lot
1   today green sometimes
2   tomorrow    at work
2   tomorrow    at home
2   tomorrow    sometimes
3   red new
```

If you're working with huge files, let it run a while.

Comment: elegant, fast with big files (few sec in GB range), and exactly what i was looking for. thank you! hope this helps other people too

Answer (score 2):

***Using awk***

**USING FUNCTIONS**

Legible:

```
    awk 'function get(file,x,y) {
        while ( (getline < file) > 0) {if ($1==x)y,substr($0,index($0," ")+1)}
        close(file)
        }
        ARGV[1]==FILENAME{get(ARGV[2],$1,$0)}' file1 file2
```

Single Line:

```
awk 'function g(f,x,y){while((getline <f)>0)if($1==x){print y,substr($0,index($0," ")+1)}close(f)}NR==FNR{g(ARGV[2],$1,$0)}' file1 file2
```

.

**USING AN ARRAY**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$1;next}{for(i in a)if(a[i]==$1)print i,substr($0,index($0," ")+1)}' file file2
```

.

**RESULT**

```
1 today a lot
1 today sometimes
1 green a lot
1 green sometimes
2 tomorrow at work
2 tomorrow at home
2 tomorrow sometimes
3 red new
```

Comment: Mark it as answered if it is what you wanted :)

Comment: sorry to bother again..when I apply this to a file of several GB the process takes very long (actually it didnt end until now). do you have any idea what might slow down the process? other parsing commands (e.g. my presented code) only take a few seconds with the same files

Comment: @BSP Did you use the function one or the array ?

Comment: >@Jidder it seems both commands won't finish their work :( is it possible the reason is my working files (see edit in original post) have multiple columns?

Comment: You're losing the second column of the output. I get `1 today lot` for example instead of `1 today a lot`.

Comment: @terdon have you got the files the right way round ?

Comment: @BSP The reason this will run slower than your other command is that it has to loop through the array on every line whereas your just matches the $1 value of the array. I'll try to work out a way around this

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with the join command ?

> join file1 file2

Gives the required result

Comment: right ..but for Mac users you sometimes get weird results..so I always have to carefully check the outcome

Comment: Do you have an example that flakes ?  This specific example (generated via copy/paste) worked fine on my mac.